# Marking mails as seen

Tags: python, email, imap

```
imapServer.uid('STORE', uid, '+FLAGS', '\SEEN')
```

I have tried this and several other variations. Can anybody tell me the true way to mark a message as read? Thank you. I searched here on the site and found several things that are not working for me.

Comment: Try `(\Seen)`.  Otherwise, please tell us what behaviour you are seeing.  Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Does the programming language use \ as escape, by any chance? If so, the imap server will see Seen, and you need to use \\Seen in the source to get it right.